# How to control the item count in each line by Android flexboxlayout?

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I want to use android flexboxlayout to achieve UI like this:

[image]

Put some items in a layout and each line has 3 items. I do not find a way to control the item count in each line. Any one can help on this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Flexbox layout use recycler view with Grid layout manager. 
Eg :

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
```